# What is the event for hiding the address bar on mobile Android?

Tags: android, events, mobile, browser, fullscreen

So when you start scrolling on an Android browser, the address bar slowly slides up and it becomes fullscreen.  Is this an actual fullscreen event?

I need to set the height dynamically for a map view so when this address bar slides up, I have a white space at the bottom until I re-render the page by navigating away.  On the desktop, I can detect the fullscreen event but it's not working on mobile.

Comment: You're thinking about things the wrong way.  There is no "Android Browser".  The browser is an app.  The OEM can include any browser they want.  So can the user (I personally install Firefox).  There is no universal behavior like that-  some browsers will hide the address bar, some won't, some will make it an option.  Don't expect what you saw on one device to be universal behavior.

Comment: @GabeSechan I've only ever used Chrome or Edge so assumed it was default behavior.  So how do I capture that event?